# Strip longest common suffix and concat in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.1, window-functions, string-manipulation

Given a table `t`:

```
id | name
------------
1  | abcfug
1  | deffug
1  | hijfug
2  | etc
```

How can I do something like:

```
select string_agg(strip_lcs(name), ', ') from t where id = 1
```

returning:

```
abc, def, hij
```

NB I wrote an aggregate function to return lcs if that helps:

```
CREATE FUNCTION lcs_iterate(_state TEXT, _value TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$$
        SELECT  RIGHT($2, s - 1)
        FROM    generate_series(1, LEAST(LENGTH($1), LENGTH($2))) s
        WHERE   RIGHT($1, s) <> RIGHT($2, s)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  LEAST($1, $2)
        LIMIT 1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE AGGREGATE lcs(TEXT) (SFUNC = lcs_iterate, STYPE = TEXT);
```

Comment: Your Postgres version? Min / max / avg length of string? Min / max / avg length of suffix? Min / max / avg number of rows per group? There are many ways to solve this, the tricky part is to make it fast. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43444/3684

Comment: @erwin currently 9.1, and these are FQDNs typically around 25 chars. Small table and performed infrequently so performance not a huge deal, clear to understand code preferable. Will study your link, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the actual examples?

Comment: funny that not even the lcs_iterate function works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aggregate function is smart and fast, but there is a **bug**. If one string matches the tail of another completely, the `UNION ALL` part kicks in to return `LEAST($1, $2)`. That must instead be something like `CASE WHEN length($1) > length($2) THEN $2 ELSE $1 END`. Test with *'match'* and *'aa_match'*. (See fiddle below.)

Plus, make the function `IMMUTABLE STRICT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lcs_iterate(_state text, _value text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT  right($2, s - 1)
FROM    generate_series(1, least(length($1), length($2))) s
WHERE   right($1, s) <> right($2, s)

UNION   ALL
SELECT  CASE WHEN length($1) > length($2) THEN $2 ELSE $1 END  -- !
LIMIT  1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;  -- !
```

NULL values are ignored and empty strings lead to zero-length common suffix. You may want to treat these special cases differently ...

While we only need the *length* of the common suffix, a very simple `FINALFUNC` returns just that:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE lcs_len(text) (
   SFUNC = lcs_iterate
 , STYPE = text
 , FINALFUNC = length()  -- !
   );
```

Then your **query** can look like:

```
SELECT string_agg(trunc, ', ') AS truncated_names
FROM  (
   SELECT left(name, -lcs_len(name) OVER ()) AS trunc
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  id = 1
   ) sub;
```

.. using the custom aggregate as [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=869f9069afb06ebe4d97e98140511209)*

I also tested with Postgres 9.4, and it should work with your outdated Postgres 9.1, but that's too old for me to test. [Consider upgrading to a current version.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Related:

- [Is it possible to wrap aggregate functions in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24984/is-it-possible-to-wrap-aggregate-functions-in-postgres/24992#24992)

Comment: Thank you @Erwin. NB I did finalfunc = length, rather than defining lcs_final_len; I did -lcs_len(host) OVER (), rather than lcs_len(name) OVER (PARTITION BY id) * - 1.

Comment: Yes, a custom function for `finalfunc` was overkill for the simple case. And yes, `PARTITION` is only needed for multiple IDs in the result (like demonstrated in the fiddle). I added your improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have an aggregate that finds the longest common suffix

```
WITH x AS( 
    SELECT left(name,length(name)-length(lcs(name) over ())) AS s 
    FROM t WHERE id = 1
)
SELECT string_agg(s,', ') FROM x;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it was very useful, and it was difficult to chose which answer to accept.